# NodeJs routing middleware error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement a middleware that will check if a user is authenticated before the server delivers a page. Although it looks like the process of doing this is simple, node is throwing an error which says "Can't set headers after they are sent".

My router's code is:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', checkAuth, require('./myAuthenticatedPage').get);
    app.get('/login', require('./myLoginPage').get);
};
```

The myAuthenticatedPage.js:

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
};
```

The myLoginPage.js:

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
};
```

The checkAuth.js:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    next();
}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't authenticated, you'll redirect the user and then try to render the index page. This causes the http headers to be sent twice, hence the error "Can't set headers after they are sent".

In checkAuth.js try:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
     if(!req.session.user) {
         res.redirect('/login');
     } else {
       next();
     }
}
```

Comment: Well... all I can say is that I need to go and check my eyes !! Thanks!